# what is the best way to launch an activity that will be closed after X seconds from a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-lifecycle, countdowntimer

I'm launching an activity from an onReceive function of a broadcastreceiver. The activity counts down from 10 to 0 and if the user clicks on it or the timer (CoundDownTimer) expires, I'm calling finish() and closes my activity.

1. is there a better way to accomplish what I want?
2. if someone launches my activity from the task mgr, it get launched again and starting to count down from 10 to 0 again (which I don't want). anyway to avoid this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean when activity starts from brodcasreceive you want to apply countdown timer but not when starts normaly?

Comment: if by launching it from the list of open apps you mean normally then yes. is this a bad design?

Answer (score 0):

**You can do one thing**

***pass a boolean extra with intent when you calling it from broadcast receiver like***

```
Intent i = new Intent();

i.putExtra("SETTIMER",true);
```

***And inside activity before start timer write a condition like***

```
if(getIntent.getBooleanExtra("SETTIMER",false)){

     //start timer
}else{

    //dont start timer
}
```

Comment: and if I want to save the number of seconds that were left, just save it on the onPause method?

Comment: ya exactly in onPause()

Comment: I thought that its working but it doesn't. I'm getting true in the if condition no matter if the activity is launched from the broadcastreceiver or from the task mgr.